# Using join based on a non-entity object

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I have the following structure:

```
Table1
  T1_ID
  T1_Col1

Table2
  T1_ID
  T3_ID

Table3
  T3_ID
  T3_Col1
```

I have entity objects for `Table1` and `Table3`. However, I don't have and entity object for `Table2`. I don't want to create it because I would then have to go a longer route of creating a composite key for the entity, etc.

What I want to use is a query like this:

```sql
select t3 from Table1 t1, Table2 t2, Table3 t3
where t1.t1_id=:id
and t2.t1_id=t1.t1_id
and t2.t3_id=t3.t3_id
```

**Actual problem**

I have a repository for `Table1` which has `Table3` configured as `lazyloading`. However, when I try to access after fetching `Table1` by `primarykey`, I get the exception `org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException`.

After doing some research, I figured out that I don't have session available there. I tried a couple of workarounds but none worked. Given that the persistent framework is written by another team, I don't have much knowledge to see if it can be done. So i am looking at this solution, which might be easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround to get the associated `Table3` along with the `Table1`, through JPQL queries instead of primary key, is using [FETCH JOIN](https://docs.oracle.com/html/E24396_01/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_fetch_joins). In some way, it overrides the lazyloading configuration.

Then, the query to get what you wanna achieve will be something like:

```
select t1 from Table1 t1 left join fetch t1.table3 where t1.id = :id
```

Edit: According to your description, I suppose you have some entity model similiar to the next.

```
@Entity
class Table1 {
  @Id
  @Column(name="T1_ID")
  long id;

  @OneToOne// also works with @ManyToMany
  @JoinTable(name="Table2", 
             joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="T1_ID")},
             inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="T3_ID")}
  Table3 table3;
...
}



@Entity
class Table3 {
  @Id
  @Column(name="T3_ID")
  long id;
  ...
}
```

Also, take a look at [this site](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToOne#Example_of_a_OneToOne_using_a_JoinTable_database). You will find several useful scenarios and how to map to an entity model.

Comment: Can you explain what is `table3` here ? are you referring table3 which is the field in my Table1 entity ?

Comment: I realize it wasn't clear. The query I suggest correspond to a JPQL query that should work if you have a entity model (based on you structure) like I add in the edit

Comment: and I am getting this error `23:44:18,077 ERROR [org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 74) HHH000177: Error in named query: queryName: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: fetch near line 1, column 64 [select t1 from com.project.persistence.entity.Table1 t1 left fetch join t1.table3List where t1.t1Id = :t1Id]`

Comment: Sorry I misspell, it should be `...left join fetch..`. If you get any other error look at the links I posted

Comment: thanks - yeah i figured that out. thanks for the help. testing it now, I hope it works out.

Comment: could you help me write the query if i have to fetch `Table4` in the same query which is linked in similar fashion with `Table3` ?